# How to insert looping radio button value into db

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm really newbie at a code and these things, I try to make absent from, but I don't know how to take value from looping radio button, I don't know how to write it in the controller

this is my view

```
 <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nim</th>
                <th>Nama Mahasiswa</th>
                <th>Absen</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <?php $i=1; foreach ($absensi1 as $data) { ?>
              <tr>
                <th><?php echo $i; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $data->nim; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $data->nama; ?></th>
                <th> 
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="kehadiran<?= $i ?>" <?php echo($data->absen == 'Hadir')?'checked':'' ?> value="1" >Hadir

                  <input type="radio" name="kehadiran<?= $i ?>" <?php echo($data->absen == 'Tidak Hadir')?'checked':'' ?> value="2" >
                  Tidak Hadir

                   <input type="radio" name="kehadiran<?= $i ?>" <?php echo($data->absen == 'Izin')?'checked':'' ?> value="3" >
                  Izin
                </label>
                </th>

              </tr>
                <?php $i++; } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
         </div>
         <a href="<?php echo base_url('absen/simpan') ?>" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Simpan</a>
    </div>
```

and this is my controller, and it doesn't work actually, so how to write the controller for when I clicked simpan button it will be saved into my db

```
 public function simpan()
{
    $role = $this->session->userdata('role_id');
    $absen = $this->input->post('kehadiran');
    $nim = $this->input->post('nim');



    $data = 
    [
        'absen' =>$absen,
        // 'setuju' => '1'
    ];

    $this->db->set('mahasiswa',$data);
    $this->db->update('mahasiswa');


    redirect('Absen');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using different names ?

$_POST['Name_Of_Radio_Buttons'] gives value of radio button selected

You can Insert the value to db or If you want to change content make simple if statement

```
if($_POST['Name_Of_Radio_Buttons'] == 1 ){
  $ToUpload = 'TestOne';
}else if($_POST['Name_Of_Radio_Buttons'] == 2){
  $ToUpload = 'TestTwo';
}
```

and Upload $ToUpload to Db

Comment: Cause that radio button is looping for every row, so it cant select in every row, am i wrong? is there is another way? sorry im really newbie at this thing